# Why won't my 4 leds turn on with this code in python

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make 4 different LEDs turn on in random orders on my Raspberry Pi, so I'm using `if` and `elif` and randomly generated numbers. I've been on Python for a few days and probably am just making a silly mistake, but please help me. My code is below:

```
    #! /usr/bin/python
    #
    import random
    import time
    from time import sleep
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode( GPIO.BOARD) #using pin numbers
    GPIO.setup( 3, GPIO.OUT) # set GPIO3 as output
    GPIO.setup( 13, GPIO.OUT) #set GPIO13 as output
    GPIO.setup( 10, GPIO.OUT) #set GPIO10 as output
    GPIO.setup( 5, GPIO.OUT) #set GPIO5 as output
    counter = 0
    while (counter < 1):
        if random.random() <= 0.25:
            GPIO.output( 3, False)
            GPIO.output( 13, True)
            GPIO.output( 10, False)
            GPIO.output( 5, False)
            print("13 is lit")
            print(random.random())
            sleep(1)
        elif random.random <= 0.5: 
    ***
    since the random number between 0 and 1 is not less than 0.25 and it will not light up the other, this is ok
***
            GPIO.output( 3, True)
            GPIO.output( 13, False)
            GPIO.output( 10, False)
            GPIO.output( 5, False)
            print("3 is lit")
            print(random.random())
            sleep(1)
        elif random.random() <= 0.75:
            GPIO.output( 3, False)
            GPIO.output( 13, False)
            GPIO.output( 10, True)
            GPIO.output( 5, False)
            print("10 is lit")
            print(random.random())
            sleep(1)
        else:
            GPIO.output( 3, False)
            GPIO.output( 13, False)
            GPIO.output( 10, False)
            GPIO.output( 5, True)
            print("5 is lit")
            print(random.random())
            sleep(1)
        GPIO.output( 3, False)
        GPIO.output( 13, False)
        GPIO.output( 10, False
        GPIO.output( 5, False)
#!
```

Comment: Have you tried glowing a single LED ? Did it work ?

Answer (score 0):

The first question is, are the LEDs actually lighting? Meaning, is the question about getting the LEDs to work, or fixing the way in which they light?

You sort of seem to be trying to get one LED to light at a time but the actual logic will cause quite a different effect.

Try the following script, unfortunately I do not have a Raspberry-Pi to hand to test it, but it should work.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#
import random
import time
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode( GPIO.BOARD) #using pin numbers
GPIO.setup( 3, GPIO.OUT) # set GPIO3 as output
GPIO.setup( 13, GPIO.OUT) #set GPIO13 as output
GPIO.setup( 10, GPIO.OUT) #set GPIO10 as output
GPIO.setup( 5, GPIO.OUT) #set GPIO5 as output

# Keep going forever
while True:
    # Pick a number 0,1,2 or 3
    led_number = random.randint(0,3)
    print("%d is lit" % (led_number + 1))

    # Turn this one LED on and all of the others off
    for index, led in enumerate([3, 13, 10, 5]):
        GPIO.output(led, True if led_number == index else False)

    sleep(1)

#!
```

Note, in your original script, you called random.random() multiple times. Each time you call it, it will give you a different answer. So calling it, and then trying to print it will not give you the value you just used. It is best to first assign it to a variable, and then use this until the next iteration around your loop.